# uchg flag on files via shared folder

Tags: windows, sharing, git

I have a shared folder on my mac mini (macOS 13.3.1) which is mounted by a windows 10 machine. For various reasons (using some specific software on the windows machine), I end up running a git commandline into that shared folder, but the files that git is creating end up with the `ucgh` bit set, and so then it can't rename or remove them, and the whole thing crashes and burns. I can remove that flag via command line on the mac and 'retry' the operation, but I have to do that for every file that gets created.

Is there any way to configure things so that files do not get created with the `uchg` bit set? I've no idea if that is a git or windows thing, or something I can fix on the mac side, so asking here first. For reference I did try [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65668/499638), but it didn't seem to affect this problem.

Comment: This appears to be a Windows issue as macOS is only the share point - all operations are coming from the Windows Machine.   Maybe [SU] is a better fit?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help].

Comment: So, I was asking on the mac side specifically because I wanted to know if it's possible to share the folder in a way that prevents the uchg bit being set (e.g. without options for those attributes). I'm pretty sure git isn't _deliberately_ setting that bit, but some kind of translation of attributes isn't working right. There's no need for that flag as far as I can tell in this scenario.